# DateTime property as two inputs on view, one for date and second for time part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is this possible to have one DateTime property in model, but use it as two inputs on view/form? For example Date part will be using jqueryui datepicker, while Time part picker will be a masked input, or other nifty jquery plugin. From time to time i need to use two dropdows for time picking (hours and minutes).

My goal is to have one DateTime property in model (no partial strings for date and time). Is this possible? Using MVC4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a technique i use to split a date into 3 fields, while only having 1 DateTime property on the ViewModel.  While not exactly what you're after, you should be able to use a similar method to achieve what you want.

**Editor Template**
*/views/shares/editortempaltes/datetime.cshtml*

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>         
@Html.TextBox("Day", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Day.ToString() : "", new { Type = "Number", @class="date-day" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("Day")
@Html.DropDownList("Month", months, new { @class="date-month" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("Month")
@Html.TextBox("Year", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Year.ToString() : "", new { Type = "Number", @class="date-year" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("Year")
```

**Custom ModelBinder**

```
public object GetValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
{
    int day, month, year;

    if (TryGetValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor.Name + ".Day", out day) && TryGetValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor.Name + ".Month", out month) && TryGetValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor.Name + ".Year", out year))
    {
        try
        {
            return new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            var fullPropertyName = bindingContext.ModelName + "." + propertyDescriptor.Name;               
            bindingContext.ModelState[fullPropertyName] = new ModelState();                         
            bindingContext.ModelState[fullPropertyName].Errors.Add("Invalid date");
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private bool TryGetValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string propertyName, out int value)
{
    var fullPropertyName = bindingContext.ModelName + "." + propertyName;
    string stringValue = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[fullPropertyName];
bindingContext.ModelState.Add(fullPropertyName, new ModelState() { Value = new ValueProviderResult(stringValue, stringValue, null) });
    return int.TryParse(stringValue, out value);
}
```

**Usage**
Add a DateTime property to your ViewModel, then call

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeProperty)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to proposed solution you can use hidden field mapped to DateTime property and modify it accordingly client-side using Javascript when some control on the form changes a part of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just pass the model to the view and use the DateTime as you would normally do if you are trying to pass in the values to a field.

To get the data back, you can either return 2 DateTime (one for seconds and one for time) and combine the 2 dates in the controller.

If you want more specific help then show us where you are having problems in the code so we can help you with the implementation

Comment: I know that I can use two DateTime properties or use two strings and than parse it as DateTime - this is how i do it. I do not like this solution because first I need to preprocess model (create final DateTime from two others or from two strings) and than run validation or other rules/operations. Have a look here: http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/ calendar for date and two selects for time. I would like to have JUST ONE DateTime in model but on view I wolud like to "display" it as two or even three controls - binding both ways.