# How can I bind multiple form values into one property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have 3 inputs with the name: Field_Day, Field_Month, Field_Year.

And a Model that looks like this:

```
public class Model
{
  public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind those 3 form values into my Field property ("10.10.2015")?

**Edit:**

Most answers suggested to change my view model. This is not possible, because my model is a meta model.

```
public class MetaModel
{
  public string[] FieldValues { get; set; } // Select Multiple inputs can have more than one value
  public string ControlType { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Comment: you'll probably have to make `Field` a `HiddenFor` input (I'm assuming you're using razor), and use javascript to set the value when one of your inputs is editted.

Comment: @Jonesy Sry, I can't use any Javascript.

Comment: Then you'll need a custom model binder.

Comment: Then change your model, and build it on the server side.

Comment: Take a look into dove answer. Maybe this is what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076573/datetime-property-as-two-inputs-on-view-one-for-date-and-second-for-time-part

Comment: Why aren't you using the `EditFor()` or even `TextFor` html helpers to generate MVC *valid* named input controls?  I don't see a reason to do what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to do something like the following in a view model:

```
public int Day { get; set; }
public int Month { get; set; }
public int Year { get; set; }

public DateTime Field
{
    get { return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day); }
    set
    {
        Day = value.Day;
        Month = value.Month;
        Year = value.Year;
    }
}
```

The entity this represents would only have the `Field` property. So in your form you can use the `Day`, `Month`, and `Year` properties, and then when you map back over to your entity you set it's `Field` property to the `Field` property on your view model, which automatically populates itself from what was posted.

I'd also recommend using a DateTime here instead of string. Not only does it make converting back and forth much easier, without having to do a bunch of string parsing, but you can then represent the date in whatever format it needs to be, rather than just the one static format of your string.

Comment: What would the querystring look like for setting the Field value with .Day, .Month, and .Year?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you would treat these as first-class properties, using something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Day)` in your view. The heavy lifting is done by the `Field` property, or whatever you want to call it, on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to make another class and then name your input elements accordingly either using the razor helpers or manually

c#

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public Field Field { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
 public string Day { get; set; }
 public string Month{ get; set; }
 public string Year{ get; set; }
}
```

.cshtml

```
@model ViewModel

<form>
 <div>Field Day <input name="Field.Day" /></div>
 <div>Field Month <input name="Field.Month" /></div>
 <div>Field Year <input name="Field.Year" /></div>
</form>
```

The name attribute is what the asp.net mvc model binder uses to populate the view model. That is why they have the dot extension there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is this problem also solvable via a custom ModelBinder? I thought I could add an convention in MVC.

Comment: A custom model binder is just going to parse the query string and populate values, so you could solve this with that. However, it would be an excessive amount of work in my opinion for something which is rather trivial. It would also hurt readability.

Comment: Totally agree with @TravisJ. Custom model binder is absolutely the wrong way to go.